# How to wire an AC induction motor

Tags: capacitor, ac, induction-motor

How do I get the ceiling fan motor below wired, and how do I enable speed control?

Our AC outlet supplies 220V, and the motor comes with a 1.5uF capacitor.

I understand I would need an h-bridge controller or something similar?

When measuring the wires, red and brown are connected, and white and grey are connected.

Here's an image of the fan motor:

[image: Ceiling fan assembly]

and its capacitor:

[image: 1.5uF Capacitor]

Since @transistors' answer, here's another photo on how I got the wiring done, in order to get the motor spinning in the right direction.

[image: Ceiling fan wired up]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqIK8N.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Single-phase capacitor start induction motor.*

Let's just get the thing running first.

Add the capacitor in series with the winding with higher resistance, if there is one. If the motor runs backwards then reverse one of the windings.

**Explanation**

If we only had Winding1 and apply an AC voltage to it the motor will run if you spin-start it by hand (very carefully). The problem is that it doesn't know which way to turn.

Winding2 is offset slightly - maybe 10° or 20° - and the capacitor causes the current to lead that in Winding1 enough that it pulls the rotor slightly ahead of Winding2 giving enough rotation that the motor starts reliably and with the desired direction.

Comment: Wow! That was surprisingly easy! Motor is spinning!

Comment: Great. You obviously have a talent for this! ;^) I've added a simple explanation if you want to understand some more.

Comment: Thanks @transistor. I'll post another question on how to get the speed control enabled, but first, let me Google a bit.